# Filter with dplyr on a grouped variable

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, filter

I have a dataset with multiple rows per patient (`RunId`).

I would like to filter out patients who have a certain `CPT` code on any one of their rows.

However, when I run this filter it's not filtering anybody?  What's wrong with the filter code with the `!= expressions`?

I have confirmed that `str(data$CPTCode)` is numeric.

```
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)

data <- tribble(
  ~RunId, ~CPTCode,
  1, 33975,
  1, 10436,
  2, 33976,
  2, 10436,
  3, 33935,
  3, 10436,
  4, 33945,
  4, 10436,
  5, 10436
)

# Filter out patients 1-4 who have these four cpt codes
data2 <- data %>%
  group_by(RunId) %>%
  filter(CPTCode != 33975 | CPTCode != 33976 | CPTCode != 33935 | CPTCode != 33945)

desired_data <- tribble(
  ~RunId, ~CPTCode,
  5, 10436
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The logic should be:

```r
data %>%
  group_by(RunId) %>%
  filter(!any(CPTCode %in% c(33975, 33976, 33935, 33945))) %>%
  ungroup()

# equivalent to:
# filter(!any(CPTCode == 33975 | CPTCode == 33976 | CPTCode == 33935 | CPTCode == 33945))
```

or

```r
... %>%
  filter(all(!CPTCode %in% c(33975, 33976, 33935, 33945)))

# equivalent to:
# filter(all(CPTCode != 33975 & CPTCode != 33976 & CPTCode != 33935 & CPTCode != 33945))
```

**Output:**

```
# # A tibble: 1 × 2
#   RunId CPTCode
#   <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1     5   10436
```

Comment: Darren Thank you!  This was driving me nuts.